# Custom Django template tag to look up a string username and return it as a user object

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I use some third-party template tags in my Django Application (maintained elsewhere) that return a username as a string I can access in my templates like this.

```
{% for user in gr.user.foll.list %}

 {{user}}
```

Trouble is because {{user}} is returned as a string - I need to convert into a Django User Object, if it exists in the Django DB, or set a varible unRegistered if not so I can do things like:

```
 { user.get_profile.about }} # get profile information
```

So I thought I would write my first Django Template Tag so I could use it like this:

```
{% webapp_user_lookup user %} # my custom tag
    {% ifnot unRegistered %}
    {{ user.get_profile.about }} # get profile information - would fail with a string
    {% endifnot %}
 {% endfor %}
```

The code I use elsewhere to look up a user in a view is:

```
try:
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=user)
        unRegistered = False
        if not other_user.is_active:
                unRegistered = True
 except: 
        unRegistered = True
```

However looking at the Django Template tag examples I'm having trouble understanding how best to structure the custom template tag, to take my string username - and send back the results as an object if they exist, or set a varible if not and the original string. I'd really like to better understand how the structure works, and if I need a 'class' and if so, why. (I'm new to programming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a template filter like so:

```
{{username|get_user}}
```

in your user_template_tags.py:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

register = template.Library()

########################

def get_user(username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist: 
        user = User.objects.none()
    return user

register.filter('get_user',get_user)
```

then in your template you can do something like:

```
{% with username|getuser as user %}
{% if user %}DO USER STUFF
{% else %}DO UNREGISTERED STUFF
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: also, unless you've compensated for it in the user's save method, django can store a username of JOESHMO and joeshmo which would throw an error. You could leave off the "User.DoesNotExist" part if that is not handled.

Comment: Brandon this looks really simple and I can understand your code - I'm just going to play with it now, thank you for taking the time to write such a clear example.

Comment: Thats brilliant, and I can use your syntax for a lot of other things in my webapp, thanks again

Comment: no problem. you can use filters like this for all kinds of stuff. if you ever need to, you can pass another variable with {{var1|filtername:var2}} and def filtername(var1,var2) in your *tags.py